# How to configure ActiveRecord connection in gem and parent app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Short version:

How to provide separate configurations to ActiveRecord in rails app and gem (living in the same source code) based on same `config/database.yml`. The configurations differ only in `schema_search_path` value

Long version:

I have a rails application (*parent*) and I'm extracting part of it into a gem (*child*). The child app is just a gem with its own models. Not a rails engine or mountable rails engine. Its models would live in the same Postgres database but in a separate schema. E.g. *parent* app models are in `public` schema and *child* app models are in `child` schema.

> As a sidenote I'm managing migrations using `standalone-migrations` gem and running migrations separately on *parent* and *child* so *child* gets its own `schema_migrations` table in its schema

Rails allows the DB configuration to include `schema_search_path` so that's what I planned to use to provide the two configurations.

I would like to avoid copying the `config/database.yml` to the *child* gem because the file would be 100% same except the `schema_search_path` for each environment.

My idea (that is not working) was to use *railtie* initializer callbacks in the *child* gem to set the `Child::ApplicationRecord.configurations = conf_with_the_correct_schema_search_path`

Using this approach, the *child* models (e.g. accessed using `Child::Name.all`) work but the manually added configuration (in railtie) gets used for the *parent* app too. Since the only schema in the `schema_search_path` is `child`, none of the parent models will be found.

When assigning the configurations manually in rails console, I'm able to access both application's models UNTIL I do `ModelBaseClass.establish_connection` which will use the latest config and make either *parent* or *child* models unreachable. E.g.

- in *parent*: `ApplicationRecord.configurations = YAML.load(...)`
- in *child*: create based on parent config

Child config example:

```
add_child_schema_lookup = ->(acc, keyval) do
  k, v = keyval
  acc.merge({k => v.merge(schema_search_path: 'child')})
end
child_configs = ApplicationRecord.configurations.reduce({}, &add_child_schema_lookup) 
Child::ApplicationRecord.configurations = child_configs
```

Comment: From the way `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations=` is implemented (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L51) the subclasses will get the same config and vice versa :(

Comment: I really would consider if using separate schemas really is a viable solution. It would require you to setup a completely separate database configuration and it means that the connections cannot be shared. Definitely not worth any organisational benefit. https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/